# Issue for nested child list for Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, swagger

I'm developing a web api with .NET Core

I use Swagger for API documentation

For an endpoint i have a return object like this

```
    public class TaxonomyNode
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Key { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string ParentKey { get; set; }

        public bool HasAssociations { get; set; }

        public int Level { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<TaxonomyNode> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

When i launch my web application on swagger page and expland my API endpoint swagger give me this error

```
Resolver error at paths./api/Taxonomies/{idTaxonomyItemDbMaster}/GetNodes.get.responses.200.content.application/json.schema.properties.children.items.$ref
Could not resolve reference:
Resolver error at paths./api/Taxonomies/{idTaxonomyItemDbMaster}/GetNodes.get.responses.200.content.text/json.schema.properties.children.items.$ref
Could not resolve reference:
Resolver error at paths./api/Taxonomies/{idTaxonomyItemDbMaster}/GetNodes.get.responses.200.content.text/plain.schema.properties.children.items.$ref
Could not resolve reference:
```

the problem is

public IEnumerable Children { get; set; }

i think that swagger go into an overflow when generating documentation for response

How can i prevent this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your model of type `TaxonomyNode` is refering to the type `TaxonomyNode` as a property.

Therefore it will cause a infinite loop if you wish to serialize this type.
It is the cause of the error you are getting